Exact categories admitting a “forgetful” functor to $\operatorname{Vect}^\text{f.d.}$
Let $A$ be an essentially small $\mathbb C$-linear abelian category with the finite-dimensional spaces of morphisms.
Let $B$ be a full additive subcategory of $A$ so that
a) $B$ has finite length in the following sense: for every filtration of some $Y \in \operatorname{Ob}(B)$, whose successive quotients lie in $B$, its length is finite;
b) every object $X \in \operatorname{Ob}(A)$ has a canonical and functorial filtration $0 \to X_0 \to X \to X_1 \to 0$ so that $X_1 \in \operatorname{Ob}(B)$, and $\operatorname{Hom}(X_0, X_1) = 0$ .
As Denis T. points out in comments, $B$ is Quillen exact.
(The vanishing of $\operatorname{Hom}(X_1, X_0)$, on contrary, may not hold. I do not know how important is $b$.)
Is it true that $B$ admits an exact and faithful functor $F$ to $\operatorname{Vect}^{\mathbb C}_\text{f.d.}$? (The subscript stays for the finite-dimensional ones.)
Here, by the exactness, I mean the following: for any short exact sequence in $A$, whose terms lie in $B$, $F$ maps it to the exact sequence of vector spaces.
I know that for $B$ being itself abelian, the answer ‘Yes’ is well-known, and is due to Takeuchi, cf. the Theorem 1.9.15 in the EGNObook.
I am interested in the more general case of the additive $B$.
Thank you!
EDIT. I deleted this post since I decided that the answer is obvious: as Denis points out in the comments, there is a torsion pair $(C, B)$ on $A$. Then, one may pass to the Serre quotient $A/C$, and use the theorem for abelian case.
However, this fails: $A/C$ may have infinite-dimensional $\operatorname{Hom}$'s.

The structure in your property b) is known as torsion pair on an abelian category. In particular, full subcategory B will always be closed under extensions and subobjects (and products, but in locally finite case this is not relevant). So, B is not only additive, but Quillen exact; and has finite length in the ambient category A (because every filtration in your sense is by subobjects in B). Also embedding B into A has a left adjoint. So your case is not that far off from abelian; probably, you can check directly whether abelian 'envelope' of B, i. e. left exact functors from B to Vect,

has a full extension-closed abelian subcategory containing representables with the desired exact faithful representation into finVect.

@DenisT Thank you for the comment!
B does not seem to have the finite length in the ambient category... Consider the example of vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1$. Do I misunderstand?

@DenisT I do not know to find such an extension-closed abelian subcategory. Are there any reasons to believe it would be nicer (i.e., Artinian) than $A$?
